# How to ensure exclusive access to a Zookeeper node

Tags: apache-zookeeper, apache-curator

My goal is to allow a client to lock an existing Zookeeper node so that only one client performs the work described by the node's data.

I am considering using Curator's `InterProcessMutex` to facilitate the synchronization. My question is whether the `path` argument passed to the `InterProcessMutex` constructor should be the path to the node that I wish to lock, or should it be a distinct path representing the lock corresponding to the node of interest? The Curator documentation is unclear on whether or not the data in the node specified by `path` is used by the implementation.

Is there a better way to implement exclusive access to a Zookeeper node?

Answer (score 0):

The path you enter is the path you wish locked and not the path of the lock. The curator creates a path for the lock under the hood.

Comment: If this is true, then the documentation for the `InterProcessMutex` class is lacking sufficient detail for me to use the class without looking at the source code. I would need to know where the `InterProcessMutex` implementation is going to write the lock state information. Without further information, how can I be sure that (1) my application code will not interfere with the correct functioning of the mutex lock and (2) my application code will not be encounter node data or child nodes created by the mutex lock implementation?

Comment: Regarding the documentation, not much I can say. Regarding the implementation - I didn't see the implementation, but when browsing the ZK I saw that under to locked node the was a node named `locks` - I do agree that if you try and create such a node that may cause problems. But when it is modified my listeners are not triggered, therefore I think the curator handles it. Hope this helps...